# Сжать массив, удалив из него все элементы, находящиеся в диапазоне [a,b] и заполнить освободившееся элементы нулями. JAVA

Tags: java, массивы

```
public class DeleteArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите размер массива - ");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        int []  arr = new int[x];
        int [] arr1 = null;
        System.out.println("Введите значение a - ");
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Введите значение b - ");
        int b = scan.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0;i< arr.length;i++) {
            arr[i] = rand.nextInt(10)+5;
        }
        System.out.println("" + Arrays.toString(arr));
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (i>=a && i<=b) {
                arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                arr[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("" + Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: Получается заполнить диапазон нулями, но не понимаю как удалить, а затем заполнить.

Comment: Так сжать или заменить? Если вы замените их нулями, то вы ничего не сожмёте.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос пример исходного массива и соответствующий результат.

Comment: Сжать массив нельзя, можно только удалить из него ненужные элементы, а нужные переместить в новый.

Comment: Исходника нет, есть только задание текстом. Вот полное задание - сжать массив, удалив из него все элементы, величина которых находится в интервале [a,b]. Освободившийся в конце массива элементы заполнить нулями. Я возможно не понимаю, что конкретно тут требуется.

Comment: https://gospodaretsva.com/zip-zero.html вот ссылка на исходник.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот смотрите ([тест на ideone](https://ideone.com/C1kLCM)) (исправил скопированную из вопроса ошибку)

```
int a = 4;
    int b = 6;
    int[] arr = {5,7,0,1,2,8,4};
    int abcount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i]>=a && arr[i]<=b) //этот элемент не нужен, с ним ничего делать не нужно
          abcount++; 
      else 
         arr[i-abcount] = arr[i];  //а нужный ставим на финальную позицию
    }
    
    for (int i = arr.length - abcount; i < arr.length; i++)
       arr[i] = 0;
       
     System.out.println("" + Arrays.toString(arr));  

    >>[7, 0, 1, 2, 8, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

В исходном коде на принадлежность диапазону надо проверять значения в массиве, а не его индексы.

Основное здесь - ввести отдельный индекс `j` последнего корректного элемента, при прохождении массива пропускать числа из исключаемого диапазона, записывая "подходящие" значения по индексу `j` и инкрементировать его.  В конце заполнить хвост нулями, начиная от индекса `j` (хотя для настоящего сжатия следовало бы скопировать массив в меньший по размеру и отбросить нули).

```java
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < a || arr[i] > b) { // инвертировать условие
        arr[j++] = arr[i]; // перенести число, не входящее в исключаемый диапазон
    }
}
while (j < arr.length) {
    arr[j++] = 0;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

результат для `a = 7, b = 10`;

```
[0, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 0, 11, 6, 8, 12, 10, 6, 7, 11, 6]
[0, 11, 0, 11, 6, 12, 6, 11, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Теперь понятно. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: Некорректная реализация - для `[0, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 0, 11, 6, 8, 12, 10, 6, 7, 11, 6]` что будет?

Comment: Если ввести [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...] - то тогда работает корректно. Однако при [7,1,2,3,4,5,6,11,112,13,14,15,10,8] - выдает [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 112, 13, 14, 15, 0, 0] такой рез-тат. Как я понимаю, данный код работает не в диапазоне между 7 и 10.

Comment: Не понимаю почему при последовательной записи чисел выдает корректный рез-тат, а при 2-ом варианте совсем по другому.

Comment: В данном примере массив выводится три раза в разных состояниях: 1) исходный, 2) после установки 0 где `a <= arr[i] <= b`, 3) после сдвига влево и заполнения хвоста нулями -- т.е. полный результат работы после третьего шага.

Comment: @MBo, что именно некорректное?  Что будут сдвинуты _все_ нули, включая те, которые не попали в диапазон `[a, b]`?  Это условие не оговаривалось, в оригинальном коде генерировались числа от 5 до 14.

Comment: @Alex Rudenko Именно так: если нули не входят в диапазон - значит, они должны сохранять свою позицию  относительно других чисел.

Comment: @MBo, исправил логику, по сути получился ответ аналогичный вашему.

Comment: @Alex Rudenko В общем да. Другое вычисление пары рабочих индексов, может, даже проще для понимания.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так (встроил комментарии):

```
package demo;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DeleteArray {

  static final int N = 10;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    // вывод в UTF-8:
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, false, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ps.println("Границы массива:");
    int low = scan.nextInt();
    int high = scan.nextInt();
    assert (low != high); // проверка параметров!!
    if (low > high) { // <- для "чайников"
      int tmp = low;
      low = high;
      high = tmp;
    }
    // генерируем "массив":
    int[] arr = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      // arr(i) := случайное число в [low - high]
      arr[i] = rand.nextInt(high - low) + low;
      // ... и вывод:
      ps.format("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    ps.println();

    ps.println("Удалить элементы в интервале:");
    low = scan.nextInt();
    high = scan.nextInt();
    // тоже самое:
    if (low > high) { // <- для "чайников"
      int tmp = low;
      low = high;
      high = tmp;
    }
    // инициализация:
    int m = N; // "размерность массива", изначально: N
    int i = 0; // "курсор"
    while (i < m) {// В цикле перебираем элементы массива, начиная с первого.
      if (arr[i] <= high && arr[i] >= low) {  // При обнаружении элемента, принадлежащего удаляемому интервалу:
        // размерность массива уменьшаем на единицу:
        m--;
        // остальную (правую) часть массива сдвигаем на одну ячейку в лево
        for (int j = i; j < m; j++) {
          arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        }
      } else { // При "не-обнаружении", просто двигаем курсор:
        i++;
      }
    }
    // следует заполнить конец массива нулями от элемента с индексом на единицу больше новой размерности массива до количества элементов в «старом» массиве:
    for (i = m; i < N; i++) {
      arr[i] = 0;
    }
    // вывод:
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      ps.format("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    ps.println();
    // 
  }
}
```

Даст, например:

```
Границы массива:
-10
10
-4 -2 -4 9 -1 -10 3 -10 1 0
Удалить элементы в интервале:
-3
3
-4 -4 9 -10 -10 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

[ideone](https://ideone.com/sxkl3E)